# pe_upgrade based module not being applied

Tags: upgrade, puppet

OS: Oracle Linux (hey, I'd have preferred CentOS)
Puppet Enterprise 3.3.0 with puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.3.2)

The puppetlabs-pe_upgrade module should allow me to update the puppet enterprise client software on my target nodes, so I wrote this module. 
It lives in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/eeep_upgrade and all it's files are owned by root:pe-puppet. For some reason, the module is apparently not being added to the catalog during runs. I ran 'puppet agent -t --debug' and nothing is executed nor are errors generated. 'puppet parser validate' and puppet-lint and neither found any errors. I probably have an extra colon somewhere.

```
class { '::pe_upgrade:eeep_pupgrade':
  version      => '3.6.2',
  answersfile  => 'pe/answers/agent.txt.erb',
  download_dir => 'puppet:///eeep_pupgrade/files/pe/3.6.2',
  timeout      => '3600',
}
```

Comment: Remarks: 1. is `::pe_upgrade:eeep_pupgrade` missing a colon in the middle? That's a weird class name otherwise. Should raise an error, though. 2. `puppet:///eeep_pupgrade/files/pe/3.6.2` is lacking `modules/` in front of the module name. 3. `pe/answers/agent.txt.erb` if used in the `template()` function is looked up in a module named `pe`. General question: Did you **use** the `pe_upgrade` module or did you **write** a `eeep_upgrade` module?

Comment: Module now looks like:
    class eems_pupgrade {
      class { 'pe_upgrade':
      version      => '3.6.2',
      answersfile  => 'puppet:///modules/eeep_pupgrade/files/pe/answers/agent.txt.erb',
      download_dir => 'puppet:///modules/eeep_pupgrade/files/pe/3.6.2',
      timeout      => '3600',
      }
    }

Comment: Module now looks like:
    class eeep_pupgrade {
      class { 'pe_upgrade':
      version      => '3.6.2',
      answersfile  => 'puppet:///modules/eeep_pupgrade/files/pe/answers/agent.txt.erb',
      download_dir => 'puppet:///modules/eeep_pupgrade/files/pe/3.6.2',
      timeout      => '3600',
      }
    }

Comment: I wrote a module that used the pe_upgrade module. I can never find a doc that discusses the nomenclature, so I don't know what words to use.

Comment: Regarding the answers/template line, I was just following the pattern found in the README.md file.

Comment: `class { 'pe_upgrade':
  version      => '2.7.0',
  answersfile  => "pe/answers/agent.txt.erb",
  download_dir => 'puppet:///site-files/pe/2.7.0',
  timeout      => '3600',
}`

Comment: Module ver. 3
`code`
class eems_pupgrade {
  class { '::pe_upgrade':
  version      => '3.6.2',
  answersfile  => 'eems_pupgrade/answers/agent.txt.erb',
  download_dir => 'puppet:///modules/eems_pupgrade/files/pe/3.6.2',
  timeout      => '3600',
  }
}
`code`

Comment: Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Duplicate declaration: File[/opt/staging] is already declared in file /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/staging/manifests/init.pp:26; cannot redeclare at /opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules/pe_staging/manifests/init.pp:25 on node puppet-zog.elel.eeep.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Comment: You can edit the question. Code is hard to read in comments. Your newest error seems to be a clash of modules `staging` vs. `pe_staging`. Is the module now in `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/eems_upgrade`?